# Completely reset Heroku config

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I want to completely replace a Heroku config with a local .env file. The command below seems to only update values that are in both files, not erase server config settings. Any ideas on how to simply do this?

```
heroku config:push --overwrite
```

Comment: Hey Charles, did you give the command I dropped in below a show?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using OS-X, this can be accomplished with these two steps:

**Unset config vars**

`$ heroku config:unset $(heroku config | perl -nle'print $& if m{(^.*)(?=:)}')`

**Push local `.env`**

`$ heroku config:push`

Hope this helps :)

Ps: *Keep in mind Heroku makes it simple to roll back changes made to config vars.*